# Agregate grouping using c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a grouped object that looks like

```
Dictionary<(ushort id, ushort sc), Timepoint[]> timepoints
```

and it would look like (1, 2) => [some string timepoints]

But I want to convert it to

```
Dictionary<ushort id, Timepoint[]>
```

and I want to aggregate that sc and have only the id. I tried:

```
test = timepoints.GroupBy(group => group.Key.id).ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value);
```

But I had no luck all.

```
Dictionary<ushort, IGrouping<ushort, KeyValuePair<(ushort id, ushort sc), Timepoint[]>>>
```

I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `SelectMany` to flatten out the arrays you are grouping together and turn them into one array first.

```
var test = timepoints
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key.id)
    .Select(grp => new { grp.Key, Values = grp.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToArray() })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Values);
```

Answer (score 1):

Extended and tested version of @juharr's answer;

```
timepoints
    .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key.id)
    .Select(grp => new { grp.Key, Values = grp.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToArray() })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Values);
```

Here is the whole test console app you can try out:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<(ushort id, ushort sc), Timepoint[]> timepoints = new Dictionary<(ushort id, ushort sc), Timepoint[]>();
    timepoints.Add((1, 1), new Timepoint[] { new Timepoint(1, "1,1,1"), new Timepoint(1, "1,1,2"), new Timepoint(1, "1,1,3") });
    timepoints.Add((1, 2), new Timepoint[] { new Timepoint(1, "1,2,1"), new Timepoint(1, "1,2,2"), new Timepoint(1, "1,2,3") });
    timepoints.Add((2, 1), new Timepoint[] { new Timepoint(1, "2,1,1"), new Timepoint(1, "2,1,2"), new Timepoint(1, "2,1,3") });
    timepoints.Add((2, 2), new Timepoint[] { new Timepoint(1, "2,2,1"), new Timepoint(1, "2,2,2"), new Timepoint(1, "2,2,3") });
    var test = timepoints
                .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key.id)
                .Select(grp => new { grp.Key, Values = grp.SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToArray() })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Values);
}
```

```
class Timepoint
{
    public Timepoint(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```